# Android fading/dimming like menu option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an layout with some icons. When i touch one icon on the bottom, in the 1/4 of the screen on the bottom wil become something like an option menu which I created myself.

My goal is to fade / dimm now the rest of the screen, except the 1/4 on the bottom. An also to make this part of the screen inactive, like for the optionMenu in android.

Do you have any idea how could I do this? Shuld I create two separate layouts, one with the icons and another with the menu?

Thank you.

Here Is ma initial layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >


 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text="         " />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/invisibleImageView"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/EditorialBoard"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_above="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:onClick="goEditorialBoard"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/Contact"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:onClick="goContact"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/AimsAndScope"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:onClick="goAimsAndScope"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/Articles"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="180dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:onClick="goArticles"
         android:paddingBottom="9px"
         android:paddingLeft="6px"
         android:paddingRight="8px"
         android:paddingTop="4px"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

 </RelativeLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/StartSelectingDifferentJournal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/journal_selecting_barr" />

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SelectDifferentJournaleditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SelectDifferentJournaleditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:hint="Search Journal">
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SelectingDifferentJournal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/journal_selecting_barr" />
```

Comment: Do you have everything in a framelayout?

Comment: I have actually everything in a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's a simple way of doing this, but your going to have to modify your layout setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >


 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text="         " />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/invisibleImageView"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/EditorialBoard"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_above="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:onClick="goEditorialBoard"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/Contact"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:onClick="goContact"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/AimsAndScope"
         android:layout_width="120dp"
         android:layout_height="120dp"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/CenterTextViewJournals"
         android:onClick="goAimsAndScope"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/Articles"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="180dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:onClick="goArticles"
         android:paddingBottom="9px"
         android:paddingLeft="6px"
         android:paddingRight="8px"
         android:paddingTop="4px"
         android:src="@drawable/button_about_active" />

 </RelativeLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/StartSelectingDifferentJournal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/journal_selecting_barr" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dimmer_layout"/>
<RelativeLayout
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="match_parent">
<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SelectDifferentJournaleditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SelectDifferentJournaleditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:hint="Search Journal">
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SelectingDifferentJournal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/journal_selecting_barr" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When the menu gets opened, set the Linear Layout's background to a transparent black like 0x55000000.

```
void onMenuOpen() {
    openTheMenu();
    LinearLayout llDimmer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dimming_layout);
    llDimmer.setBackgroundColor(0x55000000);
}
```

Then you can set the background color to 0x00000000 after the menu closes.

Comment: Thank you very much @BananaNutTruffles, I am trying to do like you say but there is one problem, I have a complicated layout with more than one relative layouts and don't know how to use your method, I added my initial layout in my question, If you could help it would be great.

Comment: Which one in the XML is your menu view

Comment: In the menu  would like to have those items: id/gallery, id/SelectDifferentJournaleditText and id/SelectingDifferentJournal

Comment: The problem, when I am using frame layout is that the 4 icons in the main layout (not the menu one) are in an real disorder. When I am adding an extra layout, so in the frame layout I have another relativeLayout and then inside of the relative layout everything you say, then my icons are ok but the dimming part is not working

Comment: Great, what's a beutifool help. If I would like to make the background darker (to dimm more), I shuld change setBackgroundColor(0x55000000) ? How to know which color is darker

Comment: This is hexadecimal. The two numbers in the 5 position control the transparency. Lower value, more transparent. Higher value, darker.

Comment: Great, I get It. One more thing and I am finished. Do you know how can I make the main layout inactive until the user touch this layout. With the on touch listenet is ok, but how to deactivate this layout? Like for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Popwindow**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) to show option menu.