# How can I tint/ dim an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button in my actionbar, when I click that I want to dim the current Activity.  Fading the alpha wont work because the background is white and I need it to darken.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893150/android-fading-dimming-like-menu-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be to create a View scaled to cover the entire activity end set its background color to something half-transparent. You can also check how the stock Alarm app does it.

Answer (score 1):

Cover the entire layout with Dim Gray transparent image (i.e.., overlay the image with the entire screen). I hope this idea will work for you

Comment: my problem is that I don't know what the root layout is - usually Linear, so how can i add an image over the top?